# How to prevent Spring from injecting @Autowired references inside a mock?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test a class using Spring + JUnit + Mockito but I don't manage to make it work properly.

Let's say my class references a Service:

```
@Controller
public class MyController 
{

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        service.whatever();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        service.create();
    }
}
```

And this Service references a Repository:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    public void whatever() {}

    public void create() {
        repository.save();
    }
}
```

When testing the MyController class, I want the service to be mocked. The problem is: **even when the service is mocked, Spring tries to inject the repository in the mock**.

Here is what I did. Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyControllerTestConfiguration.class })
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        myController.doSomething();
    }

}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyControllerTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyController myController() {
        return new MyController();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
    }

}
```

And the error I get: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [test.test.MyRepository] found for dependency`

I tried to initialize the mock using Mockito's `@InjectMocks` annotation but this fails because the `@PostConstruct` method is called before the mocks injection, generating a `NullPointerException`.

And I cannot simply mock the repository because in real life that would make me mock A LOT of classes...

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please get some help from here https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-mocking-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interfaces, especially if you use some kind of AOP (transactions, security, etc), i.e. you'll have interface `MyService` and class `MyServiceImpl`.

In configuration you'll have:

```
 @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
    }
```

Comment: I am not personally a fan of creating an interface if there is only one (non-mock) implementation, for two reasons. 1) it increases the maintenance costs (every time you add or change a method in the class, you need to update the interface), and 2) it makes it harder to read what the code actually does, because you need to understand the configuration to see what implementation is chosen (this can be partiality mitigated via very good interface documentation). One you need two implementations, extracting an implementation has enough benefits to override those costs.

Answer (score 6):

Use constructor instead of field injection. That makes testing a lot easier.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final MyRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void whatever() {}

    public void create() {
        repository.save();
    }
}
```

-

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private final MyService service;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        service.whatever();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        service.create();
    }
}
```

This has several advantages:

- You don't need Spring in your tests. This allows you to do proper **unit** tests. It also makes the test incredibly fast (from seconds to milliseconds).
- You cannot accidentally create an instance of a class without its dependencies which would result in a `NullPointerException`.
- As @NamshubWriter pointed out:

  > [The instance fields for the dependencies] can be final, so 1) they cannot be accidentally modified, and 2) any thread reading the field will read the same value.

Discard the `@Configuration` class and write a test like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepository repository;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        MyController myController = new MyController(service);
        myController.doSomething();
    }

}
```

Comment: A bonus of using constructor injection is the `repository` and `service` fields can be `final`, so 1) they cannot be accidentally modified, and 2) any thread reading the field will read the same value.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but this would require a lot of changes in the real app (and it would result in enormous constructors). And I'm surprised that people seem to agree to not use dependency injection: I thought that the goal of dependency injection was to resolve cases like mine ("In that context I want to wire a real service, in that other context I want to wire a mock")

Comment: The goal of dependency injection is to free classes from having to know how to get or create their dependencies. That of course also allows to wire a different implementation of a dependency without having to change the class that depends on it. However, constructor injection and not using Spring in tests has several advantages. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

you should put  the @InjectMocks annotation in your controller and @Mock in your service, look:

```
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
private MyController myController;
@Autowired
@Mock
private MyService myService;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    myController.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but since Mockito injects its mocks after MyController was instanciated, the `@PostConstruct` method throws a `NullPointerException`